# How to set "deploy on branch", with branch name matching regex a expression using Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

When we cut release branches for our product, we version them like this:

release/x.x.x

Is there a way on travis.yml file to set `deploy on branch` matching a regex pattern?

travis.yml snippet:

```
provider: script
script: bash dockerbuildandpush.sh
on:
  branch: /^release\/.*$/
```

The above-mentioned snippet does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. Leaving it out there for anyone else trying to do the same thing.

```
provider: script
script: bash dockerbuildandpush.sh
on:
  all_branches: true
  condition: ${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH:-$TRAVIS_BRANCH} =~ ^release\/.*$
```

Explanation for `${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH:-$TRAVIS_BRANCH}` can be found here:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6652

https://graysonkoonce.com/getting-the-current-branch-name-during-a-pull-request-in-travis-ci/

Answer (score 3):

I also needed to deploy only on branches matching a regex.

My checks are the following:

- Is there a tag?
- Are we on master branch? (Avoid deploying on Pull Requests)
- If so, does it look like `1.0.0` or `0.4.3`?

If those two checks match, I can deploy securely using the tag for release version.

The interresting part of my `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: pypi
  distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
  on:
    tags: true
    branch:
      - master
      - /(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
```

Hope this helps.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Are you sure your method works? Documentation says nothing about regular expressions in `deploy.on.branch` key. Besides, if the `tags` key is specified, the `branch` option condition [seems to be ignored](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment)

Comment: @JohnDoe I don’t know if it still works but I have used it on several projects. This answer is 2 years old and maybe it doesn’t work any more. I am not 100% sure now and can’t try it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To run the deploy script conditionally, say only on branches matching a regular expression like release branches as `^release\/.*$`, use condition field and concatenate multiple conditions using &&. The `branch` field does not support regexp.

If `branch` or `branches` field is not specified, travis assumes its on master branch(or default branch). So be sure to include `all_branches: true` line in travis config.

You can access current branch name using travis env variable `$TRAVIS_BRANCH`.

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: bash myscript.sh
    verbose: true
    on:
      all_branches: true
      condition: $TRAVIS_BRANCH =~ ^release\/.*$ && $TRAVIS_OS_NAME = linux
```